# In case of an unsecured loan creation in a non-domestic currency where will the loan payment money come from?

Tags: loans, currency, foreign-currency

In case of an unsecured loan creation in a non-domestic currency where will the loan payment money come from?

I have learned that it is possible for the money to be created and exist outside of their domestic zones. As an example there are `Euro-` currencies: Euro-dollar, Euro-sterling, Euro-euro, etc.

So, a loaner (in this case a bank) creates a deposit for an issuer. E.g. a bank in Europe creates a deposit in USD. The bank adds for itself liabilities to the issuer in the USD and adds assets for itself in USD in the form of the issuer debt.

Later on the issuer comes to the bank and pays the loan back in USD. And I am just curious where have the issuer got the USD? Have the issuer went to USA and got the USD cash?

I have come up with the question above after reading the **The Basics of Bitcoins and Blockchains by Antony Lewis**. More precisely the **Euro-currencies** chapter. It states the following:

> How are Euro-currencies created? When a bank writes a loan in the currency outside its domestic currency zone (e.g., a British bank issuing a loan in USD), it creates money that exists outside its currency zone (i.e., USD deposits existing outside the USA). This is allowed and is normal business practice, fairly common in fact, but complicates the financial world, especially when countries are trying to count how much of their own currency exists in the world. So it is not the case that all currency is directly controlled by its respective central bank.
>
> At this stage, it is worth busting a common myth. It is commonly believed that banks take money from one customer and lend it to another. This is a sloppy way of thinking about banking and leads to incorrect conclusions. Banks create money, in the form of deposits, when they write loans. These new deposits are new money, sometimes called ‘fountain pen money’ because bankers used to approve loans by signing a document with a fountain pen. If you take out an unsecured loan from a bank, the bank adds deposits to your account (increasing their total liabilities) and adds a loan to their balance sheet (increasing their total assets). New money has been created; it hasn’t been ‘borrowed’ from another depositor. The Bank of England explains this in a research piece entitled ‘Money creation in the modern economy’

So, the excerpt above make me ponder over the appearance of the money later on to close the loan. I can not understand where does the money to close the loan come from (obviously from the issuer, but where does he/she get it from?).

And in case the issuer will go to USA to get the money, then it seems to me that it is not a money creation, but more like a money transfer. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I do not understand why my question was downvoted. That is a childish and stupid action to downvote a question without any explanations. What value will the downvote bring if I am not aware of the downvote reason?

Comment: I'm not the DV. But, questions about economics are generally off-topic here unless they relate directly to personal finance. See meta [here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/expanding-the-scope-of-money-to-economics-etc) and [here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/why-cant-we-ask-questions-about-economics-here-is-there-a-place-to-ask-questi).

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea, could you, please, move my question to a correct SO site?

Comment: Sorry but I lack the ability to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, which seems to dive into money theory, but the simplest answer is that the borrower got the money from its own supply. That money might have come from selling goods or services (using the borrowed money as capital) in the US, or by borrowing US funds from someone else to pay back the loan.

Comment: So, there is in fact no such thing as a creation of a currency outside the domestic zone. Since the two cases you provide do not sound like money creation, more like just a money movement. And hence the two paragraphs I have quoted from the book have no sense. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Also your answer contradicts what is written in the excerpt. ...`complicates the financial world, especially when countries are trying to count how much of their own currency exists in the world`... So, if we consider your answer as a correct one, then it is impossible that the quoted statement holds. So, could you, please, state explicitly in your answer that you consider the excerpt provided in the question to be a nonsense? Otherwise I can not accept your answer as an appropriate one.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha I answered the specific part of your question "where does the money to close the loan come from". The rest of it regarding multi-currency economics is out of my realm expertise and off-topic for this site. If my answer is not helpful to you I'll delete it.